# Locating largest value and return it's heading from table using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
    V1   V2   V3

A   1    5     9

B   2    2     6

C   7    8     4
```

Hi Experts,

I need support to find the largest value (whole range) in this table and then return it's location. For example, largest value is 9 and the result should also return A V3.

Thank you

Comment: Do you search for the largest value in range, row or a column?

Comment: What do you want to do if there are 2 instances of 9 in the table?

Comment: lowak: I am looking for the largest value in the whole range.

Comment: Dave: It can pick any of the instances..

Comment: Can we also do something like prioritising values? For example: First value should come V3A, second as V2C, third as V1C etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have:

[image]

.

Then:

```
Sub Finder()
    Dim tabl As Range, headr As Range, mx As Variant
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction, r As Range
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set tbl = Range("C5:E7")
    Set headr = Range("C4:E4")
    mx = wf.Max(tbl)
    Set r = tbl.Find(What:=mx)
    v = Intersect(headr, r.EntireColumn).Value
    MsgBox v
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1**

This version returns the concatenation of the column header and the row ID:

```
Sub Finder()
    Dim tabl As Range, headr As Range, mx As Variant
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction, r As Range, colr As Range
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set tbl = Range("C5:E7")
    Set headr = Range("C4:E4")
    Set colr = Range("B5:B7")
    mx = wf.Max(tbl)
    Set r = tbl.Find(What:=mx)
    v = Intersect(headr, r.EntireColumn).Value
    v = v & " " & Intersect(colr, r.EntireRow).Value
    MsgBox v
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It returns V3 but does not return A...The result should look like A V3 OR V3 A...

Comment: That's brilliant!! Can we also sort values in descending order? For example: First value should come V3A, second as V2C, third as V1C etc.

Comment: Yes, but the approach would be different.  I would map the two dimensional table into a linear table and then sort the linear table.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a mish-mash of something I did a while a back. It's not very elegant but it should work:

```
Sub test()

Dim h1 As Range
Dim h2 As Range
Dim myRange As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim maxNum As Integer
Dim output As String
Dim offsetCol As Integer
Dim offsetRow As Integer

Set h1 = Range("A2:A4")
Set h2 = Range("B1:D1")
Set myRange = Range("B2:D4")

offsetCol = myRange.Column - 1
offsetRow = myRange.Row - 1

maxNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(myRange)

For Each c In myRange
    If c = maxNum Then output = h1.Cells(c.Row - offsetRow, 1) & " " & h2.Cells(1, c.Column - offsetCol): Exit For
Next c

Debug.Print output

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with an Array Formula (so you have to enter it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,MAX(IF(B2:D4=MAX(B2:D4),ROW(B2:D4),0))-1,0)&" "&OFFSET($A$1,0,MAX(IF(B2:D4=MAX(B2:D4),COLUMN(B2:D4),0))-1)
```

- The array bit is in the `IF(B2:D4=MAX(B2:D4),ROW(B2:D4),0)` - it will return the `ROW` in which the value equals the `MAX` in the range
- we then get the `MAX` of that (we need one value to work with for the offset)
- using offset we can then get the value
- and join it all together with the same, but with the `COLUMN`

The addresses are assuming that your example was at the top of your sheet!

**EDIT: WITH THE RANKING**
[image: Doing the array formula to get ranked results too]
  - uses `LARGE()` function to get the nth largest, rather than MAX

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation! I am trying to play with your formula to get the right result. Currently, it is showing a value error.

Comment: Hi @Pratzy - make sure you enter the formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter (you should see curly brackets around it, if you did it right)... You can also change the formula to have `B2:D4=LARGE(B2:D4,n)` (where `n` is an integer) to get position of the nth largest value