# Find value in a table if row and column are known

Tags: excel, vba

```
     V1   V2   V3

A    1    5     9

B    2    2     6

C    7    8     4
```

How can I find using row and column header what value exist in V2B, V1A etc. For example, if I choose V2B it should return value 2 and so on...

Comment: What have you tried? Also, this looks very similar to [your question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364480/locating-largest-value-and-return-its-heading-from-table-using-excel-vba) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366312/find-values-in-table-and-return-location), are these duplicates? You may want to try altering the solution provided in your other question to come up with a solution to this one.

Comment: Those two questions are slightly different. I am altering same code to get this answer. This will take me sometime but I thought if someone already knows the answer then that would be brilliant!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the correct column and the correct row and intersect them:

```
Sub tabLookup()
    Dim v1 As String, v2 As String
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    v1 = "V1"
    v2 = "A"
    Set r1 = Cells.Find(what:=v1).EntireColumn
    Set r2 = Cells.Find(what:=v2).EntireRow
    MsgBox Intersect(r1, r2).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant! Can I choose a range where I want to find 'V1' and 'A' instead of whole table?

Comment: YES! _________________ just replace **Cells** in the *Find()* statement with your range of interest.